# Magento 2 image upload error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: magento2

I want to insert an image using wysiwyg editor but when I browse an image using it, folders, images and other files are not showing.
I already tried to add permission, clean cache, deploy static content and etc but I always get the same result.

I expect to see something like this:
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPrt9.png)

but I always get this result and error:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7I5t.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmXJR.png)

magento 2.3.2
windows 10
xampp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once. Maybe you need to check **upload_max_filesize** in php.ini file.

You are using xampp so go to xampp/php/php.ini and find **upload_max_filesize**.

For me, it was like this **upload_max_filesize=2048M** and I was getting the same error. Then I just tried increasing it to **upload_max_filesize=5048M** and it worked.